# Add an honors & awards section

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv

Could an "Honors & Awards" section be added to our Careers 2.0 profiles?

I could put such accolades in my personal statement, but a separate section for these offering a more structured approach would make it easier to capture information about these. LinkedIn for example offers title, issuer, date, description and in what position you received the award or honor.

Comment: Man I would *love* to flaunt my Microsoft Certified Application Specialist awards, even though I'm sure nobody cares how good I am with Excel.

Comment: As long as it shows up _only_ if you have some. It would be kind of depressing to have "Honors & Awards:" with crickets chirping underneath ;)

Comment: @TimPost: The same way te personal statement isn't shown if you left it blank, of course. :-) But I have one to flaunt now, so I wants a section for it!

Comment: I'm just disappointed that the only projects section is for coding projects - I know SE is a programmers site at it's core, but I am pretty active on a number of SE sites, and manage many projects, they just aren't coding ones...

Comment: I'm also very interested in this, is there perhaps any update whether this might become a feature? As student with no internship done yet, this would make things look a little less empty.