# What do you think of Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

As Winter Bash winds down, I'm interested in hearing your feedback about the event. While I've been pretty responsible about monitoring (and responding to) questions in [winterbash](/questions/tagged/winterbash), I'm more interested in knowing what you all think of the event!

- What have you enjoyed?
- What would you like to see for next year?
- What kept breaking for you but wasn't annoying enough for you to report?
- Did you find all the secret hats?
- Which was your favorite hat and why?

And other such information.

Since I'll be [making a wrap-up report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160334/are-we-going-to-have-statistics-when-winter-bash-is-over-or-will-it-just-vanish/160368#160368) about the event, it would be really nice to be able to include some user testimonials!

As a reminder: hats go back in their boxes at 23:59 UTC on 4 January 2013. Be sure to collect all your hats (and screencaps of gravatars) by then!

Comment: Vote the question up if you like/liked Winter Bash ;)

Comment: *Did you find all the secret hats?* How do we know if we did? :-P

Comment: *takes note: "Aarthi is a hat-collecting timelord"*

Comment: It was far too hard to earn the hats :)

Comment: notice how this question is timed to get the most attention before they steal away all of our hats.

Comment: Think about the [badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160548/badge-for-winterbash-participants) for participants, or some other permanent memento.

Comment: I was going to vote to close this question as not constructive, but then I saw who asked it. `:)`

Comment: Wait - what's this "winterbash" you're talking about?

Comment: I know [it's been asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159307/how-about-multiple-hats), but I really, *really* wanted to wear the Abby and the Constantinopolitan at the same time. Because fezzes (and bowties) are cool.

Comment: I wonder if I'm the only one who managed to get something of a  [permanent memento](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=162704) ;)

Comment: Next year we need resizable, manually-positioned hats! (because changing my Gravatar was too much trouble)

Comment: Only complaint is that it was darn near impossible to get any attention on non-hat-related Meta questions for a good solid week.

Comment: Frankly I enjoyed being able to turn it off and blocking the tag on meta. Yeah I know, I know, "bah humbug" but seriously, don't take away the ability to disable it - that allows people who want to take part to do so without annoying those of us who weren't fans.

I'd agree with @meta.michael too. If someone visits a meta with a genuine problem they're not going to enjoy wading through hat talk.

Comment: @Yannis I got a bronze tagbadge :D

Comment: I wish I had noticed earlier that we can set our Community♦'s hat - left out of the fun for too long!

Comment: Didn't make much sense here in the Southern Hemisphere ;-)

Comment: @meta.michael I was trying to keep up with non-hat meta stuff during that time. Anything in particular you feel needs attention that didn't get it? (We were also heading into holidays at the same time, which more or less ruined the response time on many things anyway. The influx of hat questions didn't help, but it probably wasn't the only cause there.)

Comment: @AnnaLear Not too serious a concern :) Nothing a small bounty couldn't take care of.  Next year, I wouldn't mind seeing a separate meta.winterba.sh though.

Comment: Next year, I suggest celebrating a different shell. Maybe a winterksh or winterzsh. Or even winterposh.

Comment: Bug too low-level to report: I live in the UK and we're on GMT/UTC+0 and I got a hat for being active on Christmas day about three hours early (a.f.a.i.r.). Liked: bowler hat - attainable yet unfashionably fashionable

Comment: @AndrewC: That's been covered [elsewhere here on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159577/off-by-twelve-error-and-i-feel-fine-hat): to accomodate people close to the dateline, date-based hats were handed out 12 hours ahead of UTC.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah OK. I've not been on SO as much over Christmas and missed that one. Also, since it was too low-level to report, and I was just posting a comment, it didn't occur to me to search for a duplicate! (Sorry.) Happy Christmas/happy new year anyway!

Comment: There's a bug reported over on MSU: [Winter bash hats in user profile don't support window resizing](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6112/winter-bash-hats-in-user-profile-dont-support-window-resizing)

Comment: I just looked at those hats, had no clue what I should do with them except look at them. It seems people were manipulating them somehow but that was not clear. Do not pay much attention though, as I am too old for such games and might have just dismissed any clues.

Comment: Maybe consider scaling difficulty based on site traffic (like views per user, votes per question, some such thing)?

Comment: Why doesn't the Fez make my decloak silent?

Comment: Thank you for the hats!

Comment: @AnnaLear: "The problem described here can no longer be reproduced"? :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Hey, this is what we got for a "this no longer applies" now. It's close enough. :)

Answer (score 35):

I have enjoyed them tremendously!

Secret hats I know of:

- [And I Feel Fine](http://winterba.sh/and-i-feel-fine)
- [n00b Hat](http://winterba.sh/n00b-hat)
- [Gotta Catch 'Em All!](http://winterba.sh/gotta-catch-em-all)
- [Shiver Me Timbers](http://winterba.sh/shiver-me-timbers)
- [The Abby](http://winterba.sh/the-abby)
- [The Cake Is Not A Lie](http://winterba.sh/cake-is-not-a-lie)
- [Bushido](http://winterba.sh/bushido)
- [Epic Punyon Beard](http://winterba.sh/epic-punyon-beard)

or a round 8 (I grabbed 6 so far. Did I congratulate Punyon on his successful epic shave yet? :-P That other thing, that was his wife Laura, and like all mothers she has my awe and worship for that forever). I gathered 25 different hats so far, mostly because I am an answerer, not a question asker.

I loved all of the hats, especially those that fitted my little ninja so well; the crown is the one I wear most though:

[image: King Ninja]

but I looked dashing in almost anything:

[image: Cupcake Ninja]
[image: Fez Ninja]

Next year? Moar hats. Moar secret hats. Make us work for 'em!

Comment: Do you have the links to these hats?

Comment: @ChrisF There was a post on Arqade about the secret hats - http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/what-are-the-secret-hats-for-2012

Comment: @ChrisF: There you go.

Comment: Appropos of nothing: seeing your ninja wearing different hats was half the reason I kept coming back to meta. :P

Comment: @Aarthi: My kids kept making me switch. :-P

Comment: That's kind of the most precious thing I've heard! :D

Comment: WHAT ABOUT THE BEARD I MUST HAVE THE BEARD HOW DO YOU GET IT

Comment: @Asad: Drum up views and votes for [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161057/add-an-honors-awards-section) and I'll see what I can do... (*snicker*).

Comment: *Someone* wanted a N00b Hat so badly they downvoted this post. Meep!

Comment: I enjoyed looking at various hats on your gravatar. I thought you changed your gravatar just to make the hats fit perfectly.

Comment: @Jin: And here was me thinking the hats had been designed specifically for my Ninja! :-P

Comment: I opted out of hats, but the hats pictured above are really fun! Sounds like hats went over well.

Comment: Oh, and even though I opted out of the Winter Bash for myself, I wouldn't have minded seeing everyone else's hats for fun, but that wasn't an option. It was either/or. I would have liked it if there had been a spectator option.

Comment: @aSlytherin: you already could not wear hats but still see others wearing them.. All you had to do was deselect the hat you were wearing..

Comment: @MartijnPieters The links all give me a 404 error.

Comment: @TotZam: that's to be expected, this post is about a WinterBash from 4 years ago.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was still curious to see what the hats were so I tried clicking them. The links should probably be removed then.

Answer (score 31):

Would be awesome to have x,y offset and zoom percentage per hat.  And more non hats, with the ability to be able to wear more than one at a time.  Like mixing the stache and pipe with he fez.  Yeah.

Comment: Not sure if I need the offset/zoom per hat... I have only the one photo, but many hats.  If hats are similarly calibrated (they seem to be) one zoom would be nice... or guidelines for how to adjust my big head. :)

Answer (score 23):

I didn't really get involved (wish I had - although I did get a voting on Christmas day hat) but it was always odd that it was Winter Bash when it's summer here (Australia)! Christmas/Summer in Australia could have so many awesome hats, mostly involving beaches, shrimps, barbeques, drop bears...

> What would you like to see for next year?

It not to be odd to half the (physical) planet

Comment: Well, I felt many of the hats were, uh, season agnostic. I mean, half of them were accessories not specific to winter! That said, you're right and having it be less overtly ~wintry~ might be a good idea for next time. :)

Comment: @Aarthi I think your right about the hats themselves not really being wintery...making it being called winter bash a bit weird...that being said, most of SE's users will be in Winter...

Comment: Where I live is summer all year round and still I have enjoyed it to great extent.

Answer (score 22):

> What kept breaking for you but wasn't annoying enough for you to report?

The fact that hats didn't appear *everywhere*. Some of these places [are reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159401/hats-dont-display-on-per-site-metas), but the ones I'm (slightly) annoyed by are:

- In the user card, the one when you hover over a user's gravatar on a post
- In the user dropdown menu, when you hover over your name on the header bar
- [In chat!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159194/can-we-wear-hats-in-chat)

> Which was your favorite hat and why?

[image]

<strike>[Cupcakes! Cupcakes, cupcakes, CUPCAKES!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C__RpkuKx3E)</strike>

Comment: +1 - the gravatar+hat combo in the screenshot just deserve it.

Answer (score 21):

- What have you enjoyed?

I'd like to say I enjoyed all the extra participation in the site that resulted from the hats, but to be honest I didn't notice any big increase in new users, just the regulars going hat-hunting.

- What would you like to see for next year?

More bespoke hats for each site. Perhaps one particular one for each site that can be worn across all SE sites, as a bit of promotion for the other sites.

Also, perhaps a global leaderboard, not just site specific ones. I like to see who's getting closest to getting the full set.

- Did you find all the secret hats?

[I don't know. Did we](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/what-are-the-secret-hats-for-2012)?

Comment: I like the "bespoke hats" idea!

Comment: I _think_ the top three were: Bohemian on SO, with 33 hats; me on MSO, with 31; Kalina on Arqade, with 30. (Don't think there is anyone else above 30).

Comment: @Manishearth Good researching! For your next project - who got the most overall across the whole of SE? Anyone get into triple-figures?

Comment: @JonW: Quite a few must have. I'm on 79. I think you could get a data dump of these if you really want to know.

Comment: @Manishearth I'm just curious really. It might be interesting to know for the next one though - have a global leaderboard to see who is the most active across multiple SE sites rather than just people who are really active on one and non-existent on others.

Answer (score 20):

**H** ello to all

**A** lmost time to pack those hats

**T** o return them to the closet

**S** hame it has to end

**A** t least we had fun

**R** emembering the hats

**E** very day of the year

**A** t the end of this year

**W** e hope to find someting new

**E** verything will be great

**S** o much to use for the hats

**O** ur heads were covered

**M** issing them already

**E** nding with a big thank you!

Comment: -1 has a salutation. (I'm joking -- this was cute~)

Comment: @Aarthi Look, there is a down-vote!

Answer (score 19):

> What have you enjoyed?

Hats!

> What would you like to see for next year?

Hats!

> What kept breaking for you but wasn't annoying enough for you to report?

Hats!

> Did you find all the secret hats?

<sup>^secret</sup> Hats!

> Which was your favorite hat and why?

Hats!

---

OK, a bit more seriously:

> What have you enjoyed?

The whole event. The wackiness of the thing, combined with the fun of searching for secret hats was *awesome*. I've collected 31 on meta, and feel great about it!

> What would you like to see for next year?

More hats. Maybe have them a bit more related to their topic--this year's hats sometimes had no relation at all to the task behind 'em.

A special hat that I was thinking of would be the "Cap". On the first day of winterbash, I hit the:

- rep cap
- close vote cap
- delete cap

on MSO. I expected to get a secret cap for this, but I didn't *sad face*. We need more caps for hitting various caps!

Also, more secret hats.

> What kept breaking for you but wasn't annoying enough for you to report?

Nothing, really. Except my urge to moderate. No hats for moderating, so why do it? ;-)

> Did you find all the secret hats?

I seem to have all but Punyon on MSO (And I Feel Fine, n00b Hat, Gotta Catch 'Em All!, Shiver Me Timbers, The Abby, The Cake Is Not A Lie, Bushido) . Unless there are more that I haven't heard of. In which case, TELL ME!

> Which was your favorite hat and why?

The Le Magritte. Because I look like the Pringles guy in it:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Le Magritte really suits you well!

Comment: http://questionablecontent.net/view.php?comic=2189  haaaaaaaaats?

Answer (score 15):

From a grumpy old man:

Some of the "hats", especially the I Feel Fine mask, are too large and make everyone look the same.

Several times I have been confused by the same user posting multiple answers to a question, before realizing that there is a *small* difference at the bottom of the avatar.

Answer (score 12):

## They are all my precious!

<sup>Except for those I did not get.</sup>

I am very keen on the pirate hat

^_^

[image]

Comment: Gollum needz moar hat.  This one is just a beanie with a barnacle.

Comment: I had to go to rehab because of my little hat problem. I'm feeling much better now though.

Answer (score 10):

I felt very old and stupid while trying, and failing, to decode many of the jokes in the hat names.

Comment: Aw! That's so sad to hear -- any particular ones trip you up?

Comment: what does Wisconsin have to do with a high-scored answer? What's 'the abby'? What does Ceci n'est pas un pipe have to do with reviews?

Comment: The Abby is the only one with a real story behind it. The others were more about [Rule of Cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool). Abby is an employee here who wears bowties. That's it.

Comment: Users from Wisconsin are well-known to write highly-scored answers more often than folks from places with less of a beer-and-cheese culture.

Comment: I didn't really think about it before reading this answer, but feeling 'out' of perceived 'in' jokes is a put-off. But maybe that's a salutary experience for a meta-head.

Answer (score 10):

I think we needed a standard gravatar template, like this one for [passports](http://travel.state.gov/passport/pptphotoreq/photocomptemplate/photocomptemplate_5297.html):

[image: passport image template]

Maybe others didn't have this difficulty, but a lot of the hats didn't "fit" without adjusting my gravatar, and at least for me, the same adjustment didn't work for different hats.

Comment: The hats fit the default gravatar kaleidoscope images. If you use one of those as a template, it should fit.

Answer (score 8):

I think it was an excellent opportunity for certain folks to indulge in trivial but not overtly harmful ego gratification.

Answer (score 7):

The hats have taken over my *life* and I take a little too much pride in saying that I was the first person to reach 20 hats on **any** site and that I am currently **#2** on MSO for having the most hats.

I have asked many questions and posted several answers related to Winter Bash and my overall participation on the site has grown from basically never to **very frequently**.

I hope to stay active on MSO now, more so than on SO even. <sup><sub>If I can reach the #1 spot that is muahaha!</sub></sup>

- What have you enjoyed?

The competition, the thrill of collecting them, and the surprise when I wasn't expecting to get one.

- What would you like to see for next year?

More hats and [**PERSISTENCE**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159171/169404)

- What kept breaking for you but wasn't annoying enough for you to report?

I posted many questions about bugs but I would say [**The Beard**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159782/169404) is broken.

- Did you find all the secret hats?

Nope, [**The Beard**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159782/169404) is *impossible*.

- Which was your favorite hat and why?

The one I am wearing! It is the only one that looks good with my current Gravatar.

[image: MYHATS]

Comment: I liked the antlers much, though the cowboy hat was pretty great. Awww... they were all great.

Answer (score 6):

Hats were awesome. I collected total 22 hats(*the most*) in my [Movies and TV account](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/3271/mistu4u). I don't know if I found any secret hat though.

**EDIT**- Okay so taking notes from different users answers, the secret hats I got are:

1) Noob Hat

2) The Abby

3) Cake is not a Lie

4) Gotta catch'em All

5) And I feel fine

**What have you enjoyed?**

I have enjoyed making my avatar look different using different hats.

**What would you like to see for next year?**

I would like to see if we can let the hats remain for good from the next year (*as I guess this is too late for this year*).

**What kept breaking for you but wasn't annoying enough for you to report?**

Sometimes I was annoyed by some hats covering faces of the avatar too much (like And I Feel Fine).

**Did you find all the secret hats?**

I don't know if I did!

**Which was your favorite hat and why?**

The hats I liked much than other were:

1) Yackety Stacks because I could make the community clean!

2) Howdy pardner because I have made good comments!

3) Soup de Jour because it made me feel I have asked a good question!

Comment: You got several of the secret ones actually.

Comment: Why the down-vote? :O

Comment: @Mistu4u: don't worry about it, all the answers got one. Looks like someone doesn't like hats :( (BTW: you're not wearing one.)

Comment: @Mat, Here I participate very rare! That is why!

Answer (score 6):

I enjoyed being surprised by the secret hats that I got (and occasionally saw and wondered about).  It added an element of serendipity to the user experience.

Answer (score 6):

## I LOVED IT!

I will be *extremely* disappointed if we don't do it again next year!

> What have you enjoyed?

***Community involvement and just the fun of it all.*** It's awesome to see all of these people go for hats, flaunt their hats, participate in Meta more, and just have a good time.

> What would you like to see for next year?

- More hats!
- More secret hats!
- More community involvement! - maybe have the community design a few hats...
- Per site hats!

> What kept breaking for you but wasn't annoying enough for you to report?

Nothing, if it was broken I reported it.

> Did you find all the secret hats?

I don't know, did I? :P

> Which was your favorite hat and why?

The 2013 hat because, well, it's a new year!

Answer (score 5):

## *A Yuletide Scavenger Hunt: The Tale of the Hat-Seeking Missiles*

My summary sentiment about this “Yuletide scavenger hunt” is that the hats were great, because people had a lot of great good fun trying to track them down, or finding new avatars that looked good with this or that hat.

Some hats were a lot harder to come by than you would think.  On English.SE, the only site I actively pursued hats, even **Monarch By Right**  was thrice as prevalent as even **Brunhilde**, which surprised me.  Out of our 1,717 hats, we had around a dozen **Just Jesting!**, 7 **Moshi Moshi**, and 3 **Monarch By Right**, but not a single **I Do Say** and just one **Brunhilde**.

The funniest phrase to come out of it was when @Robusto coined “hat-seeking missile” to describe a posting that would never have been made but for the pursuit of hats.
Unlike reports I’ve read of Certain Other Sites, we at ELU didn’t seem to have a lot of lame “junk” questions asked in the pursuit of hats, one that would have garnered downvotes and closevotes for lameness. I don’t think the small quirks that hat-driven people would sometimes exhibit were all that bad.

---

### What have you enjoyed?

I enjoyed having something new and fun to work towards. When it first premiered, everybody really got in the spirit of things, sometimes even helping each other out with that last vote needed for this or that hat.

The cool thing is that the increased level of participation meant that even the oldguard got into the act, contributing more than they normally would. No disrespect, but people can become jaded after a while, or incur “kindness fatigue”, and this banished that — for a time.

This probably sounds weird, but I also really liked the color that the hats brought to the site.  I mean that quite literally. Yes, it is not tasteful to have garish colors, but it is definitely festive, like at a party.  Plus the larger versions were really well done, with  3D shading and all.

The aspect of secret hats that you got just out of the blue was fun, too.  It’s like suddenly scoring an Archaeologist badge when you weren’t even trying and didn’t know the thing existed in the first place.

In a bit of sweet irony, one of our moderators is named @nohat♦, and he managed to put the lie to his name by earning himself a **Constantinopolitan**.  It was pretty funny to see a hat on nohat.

### What would you like to see for next year?

I would like to see more surprise hats.

I would also like to see specially tailored per-site hats. I realize this is a lot of work, and that it does not scale unless somehow each site can develop its own.

### What kept breaking for you but wasn't annoying enough for you to report?

I never did get the unicorn to appear, even though I thought I did all the right things, and even tried from several different browsers, just in case it was a browser bug.  I had a hunch right from the start that the snow was some sort of video game, and I could push it around or banish it, but I never got it to do anything more than that.

### Did you find all the secret hats?

I have no idea: there is no 100%-guaranteed-accurate list, so I do not know what I do not know, so to speak. I managed to get 33 hats on ELU alone, with only one from the standard set missing: the **I Do Say** hat.

After finding the 15-hat hat, **Gotta Catch ’Em All!**, I was expecting another at 30 hats, but that never panned out.

At first, people would try all kinds of things to try to uncover an hitherto unknown hats, from editing tag wikis to undeleting things to giving more than one answer to the same question.  It made for some semi-odd behavior, but harmless I think.

### Which was your favorite hat and why?

My first fave hat was certainly **Just Jesting!**, because it looked so cool after the borning-looking hats. After that for a long time is was **Monarch By Right**, just for the work it took to get it.  Toward the end I liked **Brunhilde**, maybe because I was the only one to get it on ELU.  I made a point of having [a question about *Beowulf*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96697/2085) go into its making, but there was no special hat for appropriateness.

Mostly I liked the hats that actually looked like hats of one sort or another.  The only non-hats I like a lot were **Spoiler Alert!** and **Moshi  Moshi**: their graphics were great. The **Cat on the Hat!** was pretty amusing, what with people walking around with a kitty sitting on their head.

---

[image: All of tchrist’s hats]

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, after my first hat or two, I just disabled Winter Bash.  It just felt too much like a poor imitation of last year's [Hat Dash](http://hatdash.com) on Arqade.  It also felt incredibly out of place on other sites.

### Poor Imitation

Hat Dash had hats that were based on tags from recently released games, even adding new hats after the release of *Star Wars: The Old Republic* a week into Hat Dash.  This year's hat dash was generic and not tailored to sites in any way.

### Out of Place

Hat Dash felt out of place network-wide because Hat Dash (and collecting lots of hats in general) is a [Team Fortress 2 reference](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/) and hats were a running gag in Arqade's The Bridge chatroom (due to TF2's popularity among its chatters).  Its connection to other sites on the network is non-existent.

Disclaimer: I was the person with the third-highest hat count on Arqade last year.

Comment: See, I never played TF2, and thus never connected HatDash to TF2. So hats seemed rather out of place on Arqade last year (I took it as a rather limited immitation of XBox avatar customization), since I would've expected a gaming contest to involve more RPG-like leveling elements... And SE already has those built-in. Hats as a metaphor for skills/roles/jobs is [a fairly old concept](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4743/origin-of-idiom-wearing-the-role-hat) though, so they made sense for temporary badges.

Answer (score 4):

One of the things I really liked (as a user, not just as an employee!) was how excited everyone was for it. For the first couple of days, I was answering meta posts at rapid-fire pace. I loved seeing everyone really get into it -- and, as the event matured, seeing more and more peer-to-peer support. I know that this is what Stack Overflow is built on and all, but it's rare that I get to see it in action in real-time like this. Basically: I liked that it seemed to garner some sense of community.

One thing I would change for next year: while I'd love per-site hats, maybe a better way of letting sites opt in/out. Some sites were surprised to have been "left out," though more accurately they had been opted out.

Comment: Note for next time: CW posts look naked without headwear.

Comment: *"One of the things I really liked was how excited everyone was for it. For the first couple of days, I was answering meta posts at rapid-fire pace."* Translation: THE REPZ!

Answer (score 3):

#### What have you enjoyed?

Seeing all kinds of users wearing hats. Some surprised me as I took them to be grumpy or too "heavy" to take part but yet they wore hats just like the others! Also enjoyed being notified about new hat I got, I went hat hunting only once for the 2013 one in chat but apart of that didn't even bother to read or memorize all the hat descriptions, so each was a pleasant surprise.

#### What would you like to see for next year?

Honestly? Hats again. Make new set of hats, maybe unique for each site and keep all the hats awareded this year. Maybe not so fair for newcomers who will be in great disadvantage though.

#### What kept breaking for you but wasn't annoying enough for you to report?

The "asked X hours ago" and "answered X hours ago" text beside each gravatar moved to the right for users wearing hats while staying in place for those without hat. Not really breaking anything, just minor annoyance which I considered reporting but decided to just move on. :)

#### Did you find all the secret hats?

Not really, I didn't even try.

#### Which was your favorite hat and why?

Well, the [Bushido](http://winterba.sh/bushido) hat came as complete surprise and was the most impressive hat. It's just too big to be of real use as it hides the whole picture below. :)

So Long, and Thanks for All the Hats!

Comment: I know that feeling! I wasn't sure if Jon Skeet would get into hats -- he's a busy guy! -- but I caught him wearing the jester hat and it kind of made my day. :D

Answer (score 3):

Liked the event, but as a gamer I belive I am a little... inclined to compulsive collecting. Anyway, it was fun.

To search a bad side... short. Too short. Actually if it lasted 365-eplsilon days it would still be to short. Also, some of the hat seemed a little out of place - I mean, if the badge is called Necromancer, why a samurai hat? a bushido hat should go to the sportmanship badge, to the necromancer give a Skeletor mask... Also, I have the felling that some hats linked to vote/rep are harder to get by on lower traffic "board" (read: SharePoint overflow, [18 mortarboard badges from the start of times](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/25/mortarboard) and so on..).

Suggestions for next time? site related hats. I really hoped for a Clippy hat on SPOverflow.
Also - what about merging hats and badges? Leave badge as now, but add a flavor image like for hat. The whole with a rack page as a bonus, that shows the badges for all sites.

Comment: Yeah, five helpful flags on a site that _might_ get one flag a month is a bit tough - so some of the hats didn't scale well.

Answer (score 3):

It was a lot of fun (finished #10 on SO, yay!). The only part I liked less was the 5/10/15 questions hats which have encouraged some users (no names) to post pretty useless questions (and for some reason some users who had posted 10 questions in 3 years managed to post 15 in as many days). That generated noise more than fun.

Comment: But wouldn’t those have been downvoted and/or closed and deleted? I managed to garner 120 votes for my 15 questions, so they were not too badly received. But I wouldn’t post a junk question; people would have been merciless, and I would have deserved it. That said, the question-postings ones were the hardest.  I only got 33 hats, with  the 30-question hat the one I didn’t get amongst the standard set. Trying to think up 15 more upvotable questions was just too hard to do all at once, so unless I’d done a handful daily, it wouldn’t have happened. And didn’t.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't participate much (and whatever hats I collected happened by accident) but I liked it, and it was very well designed and executed. One thing though - some of the hats encouraged "randomly click the vote button twenty times" type behaviour [that had caused huge frustration earlier this winter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits). I'd rather if next year's winter bash dropped those hats that could be gained that way.

Other than that, I'm looking forward to seeing it again in twelve months' time.

Answer (score 2):

> What have you enjoyed?

The addiction get deeper and I started to seek not only points, but also hats. And it's cool to have something new.

> What would you like to see for next year?

The beer hat. That couldn't be missing.

> What kept breaking for you but wasn't annoying enough for you to report?

I don't know, I haven't noticed anything in particular.

> Did you find all the secret hats?

Not yet, but I will. May this cost all my time.

> Which was your favorite hat and why?

This one:

[image]

I have it on stack overflow, it's just elegant and nice. I got it posting on meta SO.

Answer (score 2):

**What have you enjoyed?**

- Watching our stats change as a direct result of the hat dash
- Trying to collect as many as I could, obviously
- Doing my best to figure out how to get the really sekrit hats (blimming Punyon...mutter mutter)
- Trying to move that pink unicorn to see if something would happen
- Seeing those I didn't expect to wear hats finally giving in
- Trying to win on our local leaderboard as well as get Security.SE higher up the rankings (we were ahead of both English and the Arqade for ages!)

**What would you like to see for next year?**

- Moar hats, perhaps with other daft names or connections to events
- Adjustable hats, so they could be worn at an angle or in a different position on the avatar
- [@Polynomial's script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159454/154443) built in to the core functionality

**What kept breaking for you but wasn't annoying enough for you to report?**

- Nothing

**Did you find all the secret hats?**

- Nope - but kept hunting. Still don't know how many there should be!

**Which was your favorite hat and why?**

- Le Magritte and the Abby both looked good on my avatar, but I really liked the cowboy hat, once I finally got it today!

Answer (score 2):

Judging from [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/hermeneutics.stackexchange.com), hats were a huge success for Biblical Hermeneutics:

[image: Holiday of 2011 page views of Biblical Hermeneutics.]

[image: Holiday of 2012 page views of Biblical Hermeneutics.]

Obviously there's more going on here then just hats, since the first graph begins in the Initial Excitement Phase™ of the site and the second shows a stable-to-growing community of people really invested in the site.  But from my experience, I made a habit of checking in on the latest [head-coverings](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/402/68) when there was a lull in the festivities or when the rest of the family had gone to bed.  I even took a moment to [star a chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7471531#7471531) on New Year's Eve.

It was a little hard that some hats were probably out of reach for our community; we don't often get people to their daily rep-cap.  But I didn't notice any complaints either.  The blow was probably softened by knowing that the whole thing would disappear at the end of the event, so there was no reason to get worked up about it.  Speaking of which, these are the only hats I managed to rescue:

[image: Fez]
[image: Bow tie]
[image: Extra snazzy]
[image: A subtle hint about how I got to wear two "hats" at once.]

Comment: I snagged this one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/t8cCD.png

Comment: @JonEricson Why did you make the time period, and the dates of the data points, different for the 2011 case and the 2013 case. Can you do it again with the two compared better this time?

Comment: @user1271772: Sadly I wrote this a long time ago and the Quantcast data seems unavailable now. My only guess is that I picked equivalent lengths of time (2 months, 2 weeks and a few days) rather than equivalent time periods.

Comment: @JonEricson On Biblical Hermeneutics, one only needs 5000 to see the # of page views/day in any custom-chosen range of dates: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: @user1271772: Sadly that data is also missing. It only goes back Feb. 2018 for some reason. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Very strange indeed, but check out this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357739/391772

Answer (score 2):

As much fun as making the hats more intricate or scaleable / adjustable might be, I kind of liked how awkward they looked on some avatars. I also saw lots of people change their icon to better fit some hats, so that was nice.

The one suggestion would be to be sure we are having hats for some of the new items like submitting low reputation feedback to let some of the newest members and accounts participate immediately. (Lone Ranger mask perhaps)

I'm sure you have some great data on which hats were less awarded and will shape things to have a nice mix of easy, obscure, hard and random hats to award next time excessive frivolity is called for.

Chapeau! It was a fun promotion in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I earned all but 6 of the regular hats across the entire network. I think I earned all but 2 (the Pirate and the Punyon) of the sekrit hats.

What was most surprising - that I won 18 on Web Applications - a site where, despite being a moderator, I'm not very active on the posting side:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's now minutes before it goes away, and **I'm gonna miss it!** When it started, all I wanted was the fez hat, but turns out Le Magritte fits my current avatar just perfectly:

[image]

Not to mention Magritte is one of my favorite artists. So to celebrate the end of the hat season, here is one of his greatest paintings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are the major three hats I liked the most :)

Well, I earned only six of the hats across the entire network. I think I will earn all other hats next year :)

What was most surprising is - that I won one hat for the upvote I did on 2012-12-26.

It was a lot of fun :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Did you find all the secret hats?

Of course B-)

[image]

And there is some missing part on [The mysterious Epic Punyon Beard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/the-mysterious-epic-punyon-beard)

Comment: That's not the full set. [This one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/the-mysterious-epic-punyon-beard) for example is missing.

Comment: @Mat Thanks. I will update it.

Comment: That's not the only hat missing.

Answer (score 1):

> What have you enjoyed?

Well, I enjoyed a lot (changing hats every day). I noticed one thing. Wearing the hats increased the profile views *spontaneously*. Each day, some 30-50 get into your profile *being curious* to know, "What is that?" and "How did he get that?".

Even the contributing users could get the hats like L'chaim, Tis the season or "And I feel fine" which seemed to be really encouraging. Coz we don't necessarily have to post questions or answers. Some contribution towards community (like voting, editing, reviewing or even flagging) may fetch a hat.

> What would you like to see for next year?

I'd expect the hats to be designed differently. But, that's not necessary. Anyway we're gonna forget about those (a long-time duration)

> Did you find all the secret hats?

No (My BAD). I didn't have so much luck. Though I didn't find the hats, I had a good look over all of them. Over here - http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/sprite-wb-items.png. And, I really *felt fine* :-)

> Which was your favorite hat and why?

To be more specific, I liked two hats - The "Howdy Partner" and "My Dear Watson". Both served as a best fit to my gravatar. I felt like some Indiana Jones or a classical James Bond on wearing 'em. Over the last four days (Jan. 1 - 4), I was wearing the New Year's Eve "thing" which made me look like a ***clown*** :-P

Answer (score 1):

My only thought was that a hat for editing/adding tag wikis or similar would have been nice. Something that encourages the community to do some housekeeping is always useful ;)

But other than that, it was fun, are we doing an Easter one too? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would have liked to be able to position and resize hats... I had to resize my gravitar in order to make any of the hats reasonable, and most were too large still :( I know that's a bit extensive for a small promotion, but it'd be on my wishlist for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely loved most of the stuff listed here - a nice mix of easy to get and hard to find, easy enough to set hats on the gravatar, generally silly good fun.

One problem - I was always curious about how I got the hat and other metrics that could be found on the hat site, but I found navigating around it very annoying.  The big one was the existence of the hat description popover and how it worked in my browser.  Numerous times, I ended up on the hat popover and couldn't single-click backout because the server seemed to deliver main page into popover in such a way that the popover would keep coming back when I clicked the back button a single time.  This was true, I think, across IE and Netcape.

I'm an ardent back button clicker, so anything that could be done here, would be great.

Answer (score 1):

TBH I did not enjoy it very much.  It wasn't particularly annoying either, I just didn't care.

What may be worth noting is that I would normally go for disabling the campaign, but I would have to check "i hate hats", but *that would be a lie*!

I don'have anything against hats.  TBH, I don't particularly enjoy them either, I just don't care.

Comment: You do remember this happened a good 6 months ago?

Comment: @tombull89 Yes, I do...?!  My memory works poor for practical things, in favor of negative things that can be acted upon.  (That's why I work in QA, after all...)  And I did not know about this survey until now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a really good laugh when I earned the policeman's hat for flagging posts. I thought it was cool, and would endorse another such event next year. :)

Answer (score 0):

Excellent event! I enjoyed it a lot.

My only suggestion (two parts): When the user earns a secret hat, (a) mention it explicitly, and then (b) have a separate section on the winter bash page for secret hats found. I didn't realize that some of the hats I had found were secret.

I would also recommend considering making the number of secret hats public, to encourage people to look for them.

Answer (score 0):

Next time I'd like to see the option to choose the size of the hat I want to wear. Each hat should have 3 different selectable sizes, this way the users would not have to change their avatar each time for them to fit. Thanks for all the fun of Winter Bash!

Answer (score -5):

I would like the mysteries of the secret hats to be revealed now that it's over.