# Are those Hats from StackOverflow has gone?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, winter-bash-2012

I don't see hats in my profile/top bar anymore, neither in others, are those gone ?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As was [stated from the beginning](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/), the Winter Bash was a short term fun little thing that lasted from 19 December to 4 January.

[Here is a follow up post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161188/what-do-you-think-of-winter-bash) asking for your opinion on the Winter Bash.

Comment: Oh! I missed it. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Dang, I meant to capture images of my hats. Oh well, my fault.

Comment: It's not even Christmas in Russia, and all hats are gone? :(