# When do our hats slowly walk off into the sunset?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013, winter-bash

The [Winter Bash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) page indicates "the hats get put back in their boxes on January 4th". Aside from the pure terror that sentence seems to invoke, I was curious of exactly when this is going to be.

I know that the hats have caused a bit of a time warp at times (for example the starred chat hats). Will this be true of the removal process as well?

Do we get our hats until 23:39 UTC Jan 4th, are they removed at the end of UTC Jan 3rd?

Comment: I'm definitely interested in the answer for this.

Comment: I'm hoping that there will be a small window of opportunity between the [secrets being revealed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212305/will-the-secret-of-the-secret-hats-be-revealed-after-the-end-of-winter-bash) and the final removal of hats ;)

Comment: @StuartLC: I would not count on that..

Comment: @MartijnPieters - don't worry, your [2nd spot is safe](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Wow. I'm on the leaderboard? Yay!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The hats will be gone after January 3rd 23:59 UTC. From the [Winterbash FAQ](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/faq):

> **What happens after January 3rd?**
>   After January 3rd, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

and site dates are always in UTC. Most of all, this is exactly what happened last year; at midnight UTC on the last day of the bash, the [hats were gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161570/are-those-hats-from-stackoverflow-has-gone).

Comment: This is the correct answer; you get them until 23:59 UTC today. Gather ye screenshots while ye may!

Comment: Drat.  So it's possible that some hats will arrive in the last several hours (after Shabbat starts in my timezone) and I'll never even know I earned them.  Oh, the horror!