# Why is the hat feature missing sometimes?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

Why is the hat feature missing sometimes? Actually, It disappeared right now. Could someone tell me what's going on here? Maybe a bug?

Comment: Or like... It just ended.

Comment: Specifically, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214808/when-do-our-hats-slowly-walk-off-into-the-sunset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just turned January 4th UTC. According to [the blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/):

> Winter Bash 2013 will run from Monday 16 December 2013 through Friday 3 January 2014.

and

> All the hats will go back into storage at the end of Winter Bash

So... *Poof*

Comment: So it will happen every new day?

Comment: No, the hats are gone.

Comment: @herohuyongtao no, it will not happen every new day. Winter Bash is over, so the hats are gone.

Comment: Well, no reason to come here anymore, I guess. It's been fun!

Comment: I'm crying, my hats are gone... boo hoo